# QAction keyBindings

Tags: qt, pyqt

On Windows, there are **several key bindings** for standard actions. For example, to **copy**, one can use **Ctrl+C** or **Ctrl+Insert**.

How to handle that with Qt ? This is what I did:

1. I got the **list of key bindings** with QKeySequence.keyBindings().
2. I created **2 actions**, one for **Ctrl+C**, another for **Ctrl+Insert**.

It seems to work.

**Question**: Is it the right way to handle key bindings with Qt ?

Full source code:

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QKeySequence


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        for key in QKeySequence.keyBindings(QKeySequence.Copy):
            action = QAction("Copy", self)
            action.triggered.connect(self._copy)
            action.setShortcut(key)
            self.addAction(action)

    def _copy(self):
        print("Copy!")

print("On Windows, use Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Insert to copy.")
app = QApplication(argv)
w = Widget()
w.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need one action and a call to [`QAction::setShortcuts()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#setShortcuts).

```
action = QAction("Copy", self)
action.setShortcuts(QKeySequence.keyBindings(QKeySequence.Copy))
action.triggered.connect(self._copy)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know setShortcuts(). However, concerning addAction(), it's doesn't work for me if I remove it.

Comment: Yes definitely need `addAction`, otherwise what order would it go etc...It doesn't assume the layout...Plus it needs to be told exactly what widget to glue it to (e.g., often action is defined as child of main window, but is actually added to toolbar, not directly to main window). Weirdly eeven if you aren't displaying the action with an icon, but only using it via keyboard shortcuts, you need to add it to a widget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346964/use-qaction-without-adding-to-menu-or-toolbar?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I removed the inaccuracy.